# Up button doesn't stop navigation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a non-empty field check in a fragment, when the user press the `up button` in the action bar (and the field is actually empty) but I am getting the next error:

```
03-24 10:56:57.860 23770-23770/com.crimes.george.crime E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.bubbles.george.mybubbletea.PagerActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2fc7268 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-480,204} that was originally added here

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
at com.bubbles.george.crimes.Fragment.onOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:142)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2099)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2238)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:329)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:410)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:167)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:192)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My code is**:

```
 case android.R.id.home:
     Log.d(TAG, "up button in action bar has been pressed!");
     String titleField = mTitleField.getText().toString();
     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(titleField)) {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
         builder.setMessage(R.string.empty_title_message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
         builder.create()
                .show();
    } else {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
        return true;
    }
```

What I was expecting was to navigate to the previous activity when the field has *something* in it, otherwise a dialog window should appear and stop the navigation. But instead of that, I am getting the dialog box for microseconds and then the navigation continues to the up level of my current activity.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `return true;` after you show your dialog? I think you are falling through to some other case or the default implementation of the method and this is causing the navigation.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev thanks man. I am stupid. Didn't see that I didn't have that there and it did the trick. :)